# how to delete useranme and password of customuser in django

Tags: python, django

how to delete username and password of a customuser in Django. I wanna set phone and OTP code instead of username and password.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
"""
.
.
.
"""
image = models.ImageField(blank = True)
number = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: `username = password = None` in your `User` model.

Comment: thanks. can you expalian how to login with out username and password

Comment: You will need to write a custom [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use the `AbstractBaseUser`, the documentation states that it only has authentication abilities but no actual fields. This means no password or username fields.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser

Try this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    #fields here
```